# Swift bridging header fail issue

Tags: ios, swift, header, bridging-header

I have an iOS project using swift language which is running normal. Because I worry about the project may miss or other, I copied the project from this address to another address.

when I open this project and run this project. I got those two error tints:

- "SVProgressHUD.h" file not found
- Failed to import bridging header

I don't understand why this error is happen. And the project in older address is ok.

Has anyone experienced this problem?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check the path of prefix header

Comment: Take new .h file and in build settings -> prefix header -> Give path of that file . Here in this .h file you can import all objective c files and working in swift successfully. This can solve your problem. If you want screenshots then i will post my answer

Comment: your project wont able to found `SVProgressHUD` bundle just re add it.

Comment: I use your method to check my project. I delete the older bridging header and create a new header file. when I run this program, the same question miss me too.I post the screenshots in my question, thank you!

Comment: I use cocoapod import  these bundles and reimport the bundle file. But i don't solve this question.

Answer (score 0):

on the file manager (left), click on your SVProgressHUD.h file, and look at the path on the utility window (right), or just right click -> show in finder. You will probably find that your file is not where it's supposed to be.